# Backlog Item Title and and Work Item Title in same Query

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to create a query of all the open work items (Tasks) assigned to me with the Title of the Product Backlog Item they are assigned to. I have tried doing this, but if I have Title from either Work Item, the Title disappears from the list of available columns I can add to the query. I imagine this is a common request, I want all tasks titles along with the title of the Backlog item in the same query. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're okay with a "work items and direct links" style query, but here is how I'd build this one using that style.

Filters for top level work items:

- `Work Item Type = Task`
- `And` `Assigned To = @Me`

Filters for linked work items

- `Work Item Type = Product Backlog Item`
- `Only return items that have matching links`
- - `Return selected link types: parent`

Then in columns select `Work Item Type` and `Title` (in this case, `Title` seems to work fine for both work item types).

The result is the following:
[image]

... which might not be what you're after, especially if you have multiple tasks per PBI open, the end report would look a bit cluttered.  You could flip it so that the top-level is the PBI and the linked work items are the tasks.